# How to create a column in dataframe that is the parameter of a function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, image-processing

I made a function that returns a few statistics, but I would like the last column to be the name of the parameter that is inserted into the function.  The code below shows the function and I would like the last column "Region" to give the value of the parameter that I used to initiate the function "NameofRegion"

```
def roiStats(roi):
    data = {'Mean': np.mean(roi),
            'Median': np.median(roi),
            'StdDev': np.std(roi),
            'Min': np.min(roi),
            'Max': np.max(roi),
            'Region': NameofRegion}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
    return df

roiStats(NameofRegion)
```

The biggest issue is that 'NameofRegion' is a 2d arrary of pixel values.  It is a cropped region from an image and the error I receive is "Must be 1 dimensional"

Comment: Just change 'Region': NameofRegion to 'Region': roi and you're good to go, and make sure the input to roiStats is an actual string or integer or some other acceptable datatype.

Comment: Thats what I tried at first, but I receive an error: "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional"       I guess the main problem is the original data 'NameofRegion' is a 2d array